# About behavior when error is displayed in concole.log

Tags: javascript, laravel

The front end is built with Vue and the API server is built with Laravel.

If I surround the API call with try and catch at the front and display error in console.log when I catch it, only the character string is displayed, but the content of the object is not displayed. But when I display error.response.data in console.log, the response information is displayed.

When doing console.log (error),
Why can't I see the information for an object(error.response.data etc)?

Vue

```
try {
    var response = await axios.get('/user/1')

} catch(error) {
    console.log(error)
    console.log(error.response.data)
}
```

Laravel

```
public function showUser(Request $request, $user_id)
{
    $validator = \Validator::make($user_id, [
        'user_id'        => 'require',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 422,
            'errors' => $validator->errors()
        ], 422);
    }

    return User::find($user_id');
}
```

Comment: Can you share the outputs from both console.log

Comment: Sorry. Was self resolved. It was my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use try catch on the axios call. Do this instead:

```
axios.get('/user/1')
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error.response.data); // your failed validation errors will be here
    })
    .finally(() => {
        // this will run always.
    });
```

Comment: Sorry. Was self resolved. It was my misunderstanding.